# How to create an oracle dump(.dmp) file using Toad?

Tags: oracle

We can export the entire database schema(skeleton) along with its data in one .dmp file using oracles "exp" tool. 
But how do I do it using Toad only.

I can't use this

```
C:\Users\kaunds_oliver>exp PORTAL_xxx/xxx@asdb file=E:\\Oliver\\userexpo
rt.dmp log=E:\\Oliver\\userexport.log
```

**As there is no entry in the TNSNAMES.ora for the remote server ="asdb"**
Also, I tried doing this

```
ASDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 172.27.xx.xx) (PORT = 1530))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = asdb))
  )
```

But I don't have the privileges to edit anything in C Drive i.e. the TNSNAMES.ora file

**How do I create a dump file using specifically "Toad" tool of a database that I am connected to remotely?**

Comment: You can use `dbms_datapump` from any SQL client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly answering the question as I don't use Toad, but you can use `exp` without a `tnsnames.ora` by using the 'easy connect' syntax for the connection string, at least in recent versions:

```
exp PORTAL_xxx/xxx@//172.27.xxx.xxx:1530/asdb file=...
```

... where `asdb` is the database service name registered with the listener.

You can also create your own `tnsnames.ora` in a different directory and set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to that directory path. But is `asdb` is the SID and not the service name then you'd need to modify what you'd proposed. For example, create `E:\Oliver\tnsnames.ora` containing:

```
ASDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 172.27.xx.xx) (PORT = 1530))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = asdb))
  )
```

then do:

```
set TNS_ADMIN=E:\Oliver\
exp PORTAL_xxx/xxx@asdb file=...
```

---

You should also consider using the [data pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm) equivalent, `expdp`, if you're on 10g or higher, which puts the dump file on the server; and you can create the dump [using the API calls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL3308) rather than with the command line tool if you need to. Getting the dump file off the server might then be an issue - not sure if you're using `exp` for a reason, of course.

Comment: Doesn't work. This is what it says. :(
`EXP-00056: ORACLE error 12514 encountered
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully`

Comment: That's the same service name you proposed for the `tnsnames.ora` entry. So it is actually the SID? How do you connect through Toad, with a device name or a SID? Do you know the actual service name of the database?

Comment: I don't know anything about expdp do you think I should try with that? and what API commands are you talking about? Are they some Java stuff ?

Comment: :I use the SID to connect to the database using Toad. asdb is the SID.

Comment: OK, so what is the service name? Can you see it from Toad, e.g. `select value from v$parameter where name = 'service_names'`? If you don't have privs to do that you'd need to ask your DBA. Or use your own `tnsnames.ora` file, specifying the SID instead.

Comment: can you please show me how to use my own tnsnames.ora I can't edit anything in C:\\ Drive

Comment: No, I'd already said to create it in a different directory. Example added.

Comment: I tried the tns_admin thing but it still doesn't work bro. It throws the same error.

Comment: @Oliver - Which error - 'does not currently know of service'? Did you change the `tnsnames.ora` to have `SID = asdb`?

Comment: :Well since I can't edit the tnsnames of C drive  I added my own version of it in D:\ Drive(and it has SID=asdb). And set the TNS_ADMIN as you said but all in vain.

Comment: It worked Awesome. I created y own tnsnames.ora and set it's location in TNS_ADMIN environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

What is your Toad version?

I have 9.5 here and there are three options:

- Database > Export > Export Utility Wizard
- Database > Export > Export DDL
- Database > Export > Generate Database Script

There's one last option, in case you only need to get the 'skeleton' for one schema:

- Database > Export > Generate schema script

Have you tried any of that?

[EDIT]
I've tried Alex Poole approach and it didn't work for me either.

Sqlplus to the entry:

```
p08[oracle] (sigepsti) /oracle/product/11.2.0/db/network/admin$ sqlplus system@sigepsti

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Jul 31 17:07:23 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

(sigepsti)SQL> exit
```

Expdp error (exp gets the same error):

```
p08[oracle] (sigepsti) /oracle/product/11.2.0/db/network/admin$ tnsping sigepsti

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 31-JUL-2014 17:07:37

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dborasigepsti)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = sigepsti)))
OK (0 msec)
p08[oracle] (sigepsti) /oracle/product/11.2.0/db/network/admin$ expdp system@'dborasigepsti:1521/sigepsti'

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Jul 31 17:07:50 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDE-12504: operation generated ORACLE error 12504
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

Comment: Well I am using version 11.6 of Toad. **I want the data as well as the skeleton.** I tried  Export Utility Wizard, but at the last step it asks for an .exe file of where the Wizard is located. Any inputs on this ?

Comment: http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC127938
If Toad cannot find this executable, the error "The Oracle Export Utility executable must be specified" displays.
To specify the location of the Oracle Export Utility
Select View | Toad Options | Executables.
Enter the path in the Export box.